# Deserialize List of Maps in RestTemplate

Tags: xml, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've tried to find a solution here but with no success.
I have external service that serializes some data and returns xml in form:

```
<linked-list>
  <linked-hash-map>
     <entry>
       <string>key1</string>
       <string>value</string>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <string>key2</string>
       <string>value2</string>
     </entry>
  </linked-hash-map>
  <linked-hash-map>
     ....
  </linked-hash-map>
</linked-list>
```

Basically it returns List of Maps `List<Map<String, String>>`

In my application I need to deserialize it using Spring's RestTemplate.
Relying on default message converters all I get is list of maps, but each map contains only one element with key "entry" and the value seems to be the last element in original (xml) map.

Is there a way for this to work "out of the box" using some existing coverter, or do I need a custom one? And also using custom, how to bypass deserializing by ex. `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` or `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the simplest solution was to fetch this resource as xml string and then convert/deserialize using for example Xsream

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
List list = (List) xStream.fromXML(xmlString);
```